# How do I add the method AddStackExchangeRedisCache to IServiceCollection in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, redis, stackexchange.redis

I have this startup.cs file that adds the different services to my application. One of the services I need to add is AddStackExchangeRedisCache but I am getting an error that says

**"IServiceCollection does not contain a definition for AddStackExchangeRedisCache and no accessible extension method AddStackExchangeRedisCache accepting a first argument of type IServiceCollection could be found (are you missing a using directive or an asssembly reference?)?"**

I have the following stack exchange redis refernce in my CSPROJ

```
    <PackageReference Include="StackExchange.Redis" Version="2.6.66" />
```

And the method where I am trying to add the service is as follows.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
    services.AddStackExchangeRedisCache(options =>
        {
           // some code here
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Install [`Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.StackExchangeRedis`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.StackExchangeRedis) nuget package.